# using for loop in ansible to fetch the ip address from a file kept on host server and ping to those ip servers to check wether those are alive or not

Tags: ansible

I need to write ansible playbook, to fetch the ip address from the notepad file placed on the host server.I need to write an playbook which will iterate to the notepad file and provide me ip address. Further i will use ping command to check wether those servers are alive or not. Please suggest how can i write the playbook which will iterate to one notepad file placed on the host, pick up the ip address and ping it to check wether that ip is alive or not.

these are the details of notepad file placed on the host server.

```
12.82.240.174   wnaca3012is #CLLI
12.82.240.166   ok3ca3022is #CLLI
12.82.224.62    dsail301is  #CLLI
12.82.224.70    prail301is  #CLLI
```

> below the playbook

```
- name: "Fetch the ip of all the servers from hosts.new file"
  command: for i in `awk '{print $1}' hosts.new`
            do echo "$i"
            done
  args:
    chdir: "/home/dp794d/"
  failed_when: "output.rc > 1"
  register: output
```

> Error are -

```
fatal: [zlp12036]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "for i in '`awk' '{print $1}' 'hosts.new`' do echo '$i' done", "failed": true, "failed_when_result": true, "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

fatal: [zlp12037]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "for i in '`awk' '{print $1}' 'hosts.new`' do echo '$i' done", "failed": true, "failed_when_result": true, "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}

Comment: Please share a sample of code you've already tried.

Comment: And why do you need to write an Ansible playbook for that? What unique Ansible features do you think will facilitate the task?

Comment: Please see the playbook and suggest what needs to be done

Answer (score 0):

I just leave a cite from the ansible "best practice essentials" [Blog Post](https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-best-practices-essentials) here:

> Ansible is a desired state engine by design. If you’re trying to “write code” in your plays and roles, you’re setting yourself up for failure. Our YAML-based playbooks were never meant to be for programming.

The Task your trying to accomplish would be easier with a shell script, which converts your text file to an ansible inventory. But this still seems kind of hacky. Without knowing the exact circumstances, I'd suggest asking, where these ips come from, and if theres a way of gathering them without parsing the text file. Also, have a look at ([Dynamic Inventories](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html)) , so you can create your Inventory during execution time.

Hope this helps!

p.s: I'd rather have this as a comment, but my reputation is not high enough to comment on every question.